# SEO: Subdomains or subfolders for Wiki?

Tags: seo, subdomain, wiki, subdirectory

I'm currently working on a multilingual Wiki and need to decide if I should use subdomains or subfolders to separate each language.

I know that most people would normally recommend subfolders for SEO. But since Wikipedia is using subdomains, I was wondering if subdomains would be a better approach, since it will help differentiate the search results for every language and probably pay out in the long run when it comes down to the Top 10 search results.

Answer (score 5):

the pros and cons directly from google
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/03/working-with-multi-regional-websites.html
advice will not get any better than this.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different issues here: the way your Wiki is structured, and the way your URLs are structured.  In MediaWiki, it's recommended practice to set up a separate instance for each language, since this:

- Allows easy interwiki linking
- Makes it easy to default the interface language to the content language
- Stop search results from bleeding across languages (search in the French wiki, get only French answers)

The way this is shown to the user, on the other hand, is your call.  Wikipedia opts to use different domains, eg. en.wikipedia.org and fr.wikipedia.org.  Wikitravel uses the same domain but different subdirectories, eg. wikitravel.org/en and wikitravel.org/fr.  I'm not aware of any major SEO implications (both styles show up fine in Google), but using subdomains is a bit easier to set up since you don't need to touch MediaWiki's default paths (/w, /wiki).

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how much content you'll have. If it's a huge/popular site like wikipedia, each subdomain still has a substantial amount of traffic, and will keep high rankings. If it's a smaller site with less traffic, the pagerank will be divided among the subdomains, and SEO won't be as good.

Comment: what is the advantage of choosing subdomains?

Comment: It looks cooler! But seriously, it's an easier way to programmatically track data (grab the subdomain and load data from a different table), Google likes it when different languages sit on different domains, cookies are easier to segregate, different favicon's without a meta tag...

Comment: does google like too if I have languages in my route? de/ en/ ??